# How do I choose which properties to serialize for a JSON object at runtime?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have an object with several properties:

```
public class Contacts
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string CompanyType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string PKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string SubscriptionDate { get; set; }

}
```

In my web service an array of this object gets serialized and served to client as JSON using a method in Newtonsoft.Json:

`context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { ContactsArray = contactsArray }));`

I want to change my service so the client can specify which fields they want serialized so if they send their request as:

`http://myservice.com?fields=Name,City,State`

Only Name, City, and State will be serialized, but I don't know how to do this on the fly.

I read about the `ShouldSerialzeProperty()` method, but I don't know what I should be checking for in the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I came up with involves using reflection to get a list of properties on my object and change the value of the properties not listed by the user to null:

```
string[] fields = context.Request.QueryString["Fields"].Split(',');
string[] properties = typeof(Contacts).GetProperties().Select(r => r.Name).ToArray();
fields = properties.Where(r => !fields.Contains(r)).ToArray();
foreach (string field in fields)
{
    foreach (Contacts item in contactsArray)
    {
        item.GetType().GetProperty(field).SetValue(item, null)
    }
}
```

I am not sure if it is best practices to use reflection, but I wanted to write this so that it will work no matter how I change my data object.

I then used the `ShouldSerializeProperty()` method in my data object to check if the value is null. If it is null, the property is not serialized. So for example, for the City Property:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeCity() { return !(City == null); }
[JsonProperty]
public string City { get; set; }
```